# Owin new project throws NullReference

Tags: c#, .net-core, owin

New dotnet core project with only one source code file

```
> dotnet run
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Utilities.SettingsLoader.FromConfigImplementation..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Utilities.SettingsLoader.<>c.<LoadFromConfig>b__1_0()
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Func`1 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Utilities.SettingsLoader.LoadFromConfig(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.StartContext..ctor(StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.DirectHostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.HostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
   at TestProgram.Program.Main(String[] args) in 
...\Program.cs:line 13
```

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;

namespace TestProgram
{
    class Startup {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder builder) { }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://127.0.0.1:3000")) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies, my previous answer was applicable to .NET Framework (proper). Katana isn't supported on .NET Core, you'll need to use an ASP.NET Core project instead. REF: [.Net core2.0 console application #7261](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/7261)